# Solving the curve equation for logarithmic decay using two anchor points.

Tags: logarithms, algebraic-curves

I would like to have an adaptable logarithmic curve equation that I can then find y for any value of x.

I have two points *(x1,y1)* and *(x2,y2)*.

My data requires **constant decay** (financial discounting of cash flows) and crosses the y axis. So with the two anchor points, what would be the generalised line equation (like slope intercept) for logarithmic decay that crosses the y axis?

For arguments sake, it might help to have x=0 as an asymptote, though this is not the reality of my data. **It would be ideal to be able to adjust a constant to change the slope of the logarithmic decay curve.** I dont know if this is possible.

Thank you!

Some sample data:
Example 1: *(8,2609) (39.14,0)*
Example 2: *(8,972) (13,0)*
Example 3: *(5,1000) (7.9,0)*